# Negative Number, Positive Numbers, pointers, and characters

Tags: pointers, character

I'm trying to figure out this program; it is an averaging program and it requires user input of:

> p 4 p 7 p 2 n 1 e sum 12 average: 4

The user enters whether he was a positive number or negative.
We are asked to use `int real_number(int* value`) and make value a pointer to where the input value will be stored.

So far I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int real_number(int* value);

int real_number(int* value)
{
    char *n = "negative";
    char *p = "positive";
    char *e = "end";
    int *sum = 0;
    int *avg = 0;

    while(sum = 0)
    {
        printf(" \n");
        scanf("%d", &sum);
    }
}

int main()
{

}
```

I know it is not much, but I'm lost; any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to read characters while your character is different "e". Secondly you have an infinite cicle. In while loop modify the condition with == .
You need to have a counter to count how many numbers you entered. While you read numbers you must add these numbers to sum and count one.
Finally, in the output you write sum/counter

Comment: How would I go about adding the counters and reading the characters?

Comment: In C is a method called isdigit(). Read character and do like that: If(isdigit(ch)) do something. Isdigit means If is number